# What is slowing down sorting the pairs on a key?

Tags: c++, sorting, optimization, stl, icu

### Timing after implementing the accepted answer

Changing the lambda definition from:

```
[] (String_pair x, String_pair y) {
    return x.first < y.first;
}
```

to:

```
[] (const String_pair &x, const String_pair &y) {
    return x.first < y.first;
}
```

Cuts down the sorting time to 0.23 sec. This is still slightly slower than using `sort`, which is not surprising. Most of the strings with the same key are probably different already on the first character, and only 1/8 of all elements in the vector have keys that appear more than once anyway.

### The original question

A toy problem from "Programming Pearls", finding anagrams in the English language. This is not homework, but you can treat the question as if it were. To solve this, I implemented the textbook solution:

1. Calculate a signature for each word in the dictionary (the word itself, sorted by characters)
2. Sort by signatures (all words are in {signature, word} pairs)
3. Output the runs with the same signature with length greater than 1.

This is of course trivial, to make it a bit more interesting I used the ICU library ([with help from Roland Illig](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/136479/62591)) so that the program doesn't choke up on non-ascii characters and could find anagrams in say Finnish.

Here follows the complete program. It is admittedly a bit long, but it is not easy to generate a realistic test input and output in less code.

```
$ cat find-anagrams.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include "unicode/ustream.h"
#include "unicode/unistr.h"
#include "unicode/schriter.h"

#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    using String = icu::UnicodeString;
    using String_pair = std::pair<String, String>;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto start = steady_clock::now();

    // sign
    std::vector<String_pair> ws;
    String w;
    while (std::cin >> w) {
        String k{w};
        auto n = k.length();
        UChar *begin = k.getBuffer(n);
        if (!begin) return 1;
        std::stable_sort(begin, begin + n);
        k.releaseBuffer(n);
        ws.emplace_back(k, w);
    }
    auto sign_done = steady_clock::now();

    // sort
    std::stable_sort(ws.begin(), ws.end(),
            [] (String_pair x, String_pair y) {
                return x.first < y.first;
            });
    auto sort_done = steady_clock::now();

    // squash
    auto begin = ws.cbegin();
    while (begin != ws.cend()) {
        auto sig = begin->first;
        auto run_end = std::partition_point(begin, ws.cend(),
                [&sig] (String_pair x) {
                    return sig == x.first;
                });
        if ((run_end - begin) > 1) {
            std::cout << begin->second;
            ++begin;
            while (begin != run_end) {
                std::cout << ' ' << begin->second;
                ++begin;
            }
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
        begin = run_end;
    }
    auto squash_done = steady_clock::now();

    duration<double> time;
    time = duration_cast<duration<double>>(sign_done - start);
    std::cerr
        << "Read and calculate signatures:\n"
        << '\t' << time.count() << " sec\n";
    time = duration_cast<duration<double>>(sort_done - sign_done);
    std::cerr
        << "Sort by signatures:\n"
        << '\t' << time.count() << " sec\n";

    time = duration_cast<duration<double>>(squash_done - sort_done);
    std::cerr
        << "Squash and output:\n"
        << '\t' << time.count() << " sec\n";
    time = duration_cast<duration<double>>(squash_done - start);
    std::cerr
        << "Total:\n"
        << '\t' << time.count() << " sec\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This is the compiler I am using:

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-libmpx --with-system-zlib --with-isl --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-clocale=gnu --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libssp --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-plugin --enable-install-libiberty --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-gnu-indirect-function --disable-multilib --disable-werror --enable-checking=release
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.1.1 20160707 (GCC)
```

This is how I compile it:

```
g++  --std=c++0x  -pedantic -Wall -O2 -std=c++14  -L/usr/lib -licui18n -licuuc -licudata   -licuio  find-anagrams.cpp -o cpp-find-anagrams
```

And this is how I run it, also showing the timings:

```
./cpp-find-anagrams < clean-words | sort > cpp-result
Read and calculate signatures:
    0.328156 sec
Stable sort by signatures:
    0.512024 sec
Squash and output:
    0.189494 sec
Total:
    1.02967 sec
```

`clean-words` are the words as found in `/usr/share/dict/words`, passed through the following:

```
sed -n '/'"'"'s$/!p' | tr [:upper:] [:lower:] | sort --unique
```

In other words, get rid of the words with apostrophes, all capitals, and all capitalized duplicates.

We observe that sorting, using `std::stable_sort` and a lambda, is taking way too long. For comparison, if I sort on the whole pair, it takes about half that time. Changing, in the above program:

```
    // sort
    std::stable_sort(ws.begin(), ws.end(),
            [] (String_pair x, String_pair y) {
                return x.first < y.first;
            });
```

to:

```
    // sort
    std::sort(ws.begin(), ws.end());
```

Gives the following timings:

```
./cpp-find-anagrams < clean-words | sort > cpp-result
Read and calculate signatures:
    0.338751 sec
Sort pairs:
    0.216526 sec
Squash and output:
    0.168725 sec
Total:
    0.724002 sec
```

(0.51 sec to 0.22 sec)

Of course, the two sorts give identical results, because the words in the input file are already sorted. Notably, it is not a `sort` vs `stable_sort` issue. Using `stable_sort` (I know it is unnecessary with this input, but anyway), so changing to:

```
    // sort
    std::stable_sort(ws.begin(), ws.end());
```

Changes the timings only minimally:

```
./cpp-find-anagrams < clean-words | sort > cpp-result
Read and calculate signatures:
    0.334139 sec
Stable sort by signatures:
    0.264751 sec
Squash and output:
    0.180663 sec
Total:
    0.779552 sec
```

(0.22 sec to 0.26 sec)

While trying to figure out what is going on, I implemented the same algorithm in SWI-Prolog, and noticed that the built-in `sort` and `keysort` predicates show the expected difference, namely, `sort` needs longer than `keysort`. With the following implementation (again, the full program):

```
$ cat find-anagrams.pl
:- use_module(library(apply_macros)).
:- use_module(library(pairs)).

main :-
    statistics(cputime, Start),
    read_words(Ws),
    sign_words(Ws, Signed),
    statistics(cputime, Sign_done),
    keysort(Signed, Sorted),
    statistics(cputime, Sort_done),
    squash(Sorted, Anagrams),
    maplist(anagrams_string, Anagrams, Str),
    atomics_to_string(Str, "\n", Output),
    format(current_output, "~s~n", [Output]),
    statistics(cputime, Squash_done),
    format(user_error,
        "Read and calculate signatures:\n\t~f sec~n\c
         Sort by signatures:\n\t~f sec~n\c
         Squash and output:\n\t~f sec~n\c
         Total:\n\t~f sec\n",
        [Sign_done - Start,
         Sort_done - Sign_done,
         Squash_done - Sort_done,
         Squash_done - Start]),
    halt.
main :- halt(1).

anagrams_string(Anagrams, Str) :-
    atomics_to_string(Anagrams, " ", Str).

read_words(Ws) :-
    read_string(current_input, _, Input),
    split_string(Input, "\n", "", Ws).

sign_words(Ws, Signed) :-
    maplist(string_codes, Ws, Ws_codes),
    maplist(sort(0, @=<), Ws_codes, Ss_codes),
    maplist(string_codes, Ss, Ss_codes),
    pairs_keys_values(Signed, Ss, Ws).

squash(Sorted, Anagrams) :-
    group_pairs_by_key(Sorted, Grouped),
    groups_anagrams(Grouped, Anagrams).

groups_anagrams([], []).
groups_anagrams([_-Set|Rest], As) :-
    length(Set, N),
    (   N > 1
    ->  As = [Set|As0]
    ;   As = As0
    ),
    groups_anagrams(Rest, As0).
```

This is the Prolog I am using:

```
$ swipl -v
SWI-Prolog version 7.3.24 for x86_64-linux
```

I "compile" the program (create a "saved state" for the interpreter):

```
swipl -q -O --goal=main -o swi-find-anagrams -c find-anagrams.pl
```

And run it:

```
./swi-find-anagrams < clean-words | sort > swi-result
Read and calculate signatures:
    0.928485 sec
Stable sort by signatures:
    0.174832 sec
Squash and output:
    0.183567 sec
Total:
    1.286884 sec
```

When I change

```
keysort(Signed, Sorted),
```

with

```
sort(Signed, Sorted),
```

I get the following increased running time for the sorting:

```
./swi-find-anagrams < clean-words | sort > swi-result
Read and calculate signatures:
    0.935780 sec
Sort pairs:
    0.269151 sec
Squash and output:
    0.187508 sec
Total:
    1.392440 sec
```

(0.17 to 0.27 sec)

The final result of the sort is the same, but, as expected, sorting only by keys is considerably faster.

### The question finally

What am I missing? Why is doing less costing more?

I know I can use a map to achieve the same end result, but still it is interesting to know what is causing this considerable slowdown.

Comment: This `--std=c++0x ... -std=c++14` is harmless but a bit silly. The second one will overrule the first, so just get rid of the "c++0x" bit.

Comment: If you don't need the properties of `std::stable_sort` consider using `std::sort` instead - it is faster. Also consider the parallel version of sort.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Well spotted :) the first one comes from `icu-config`, I didn't want to show the Makefile on top of everything else. I simply added the `=c++14` so that I can use `auto` in places where I couldn't otherwise, and couldn't easily figure out how to make `icu-config` not put this there.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes, please see the question. I would need the properties of `stable_sort`, if sorting only on key was indeed faster than sorting on key-value, as one would expect (but it isn't, which is the question).

Comment: Have you tried other optimization levels than `-O2`? Like `-Os`, `-O1`, `-O3` & `-Ofast`?

Comment: No, I haven't yet. I willl do it and add this to the question.

Comment: Have you tried passing your String_pair args by const ref in the lambda?

Comment: @rectummelancolique I can't believe I missed this. It indeed cuts the time by two. You should write this up as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is doing less costing more?

Because you are doing more - copying all strings multiple times in the lamba taking time. As stated in documentation [std::stable_sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort):

> O(N·log2(N)), where N = std::distance(first, last) applications of cmp.

So for every call of cmp you copy 4 strings. Change parameters type to const reference and remeasure.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to have been the real problem. I can't believe I overlooked this. With this, the stable sort on the key gives about the same time as the sort on the key-value pair for this input. Btw, about 1/8 of the keys appear more than once.

Comment: That's an absolutely excellent answer. I'd like to know though why my answer (which was posted an hour earlier and comes to the same conclusion) was voted down -1. while this answer is voted +5 and accepted. I'd like to improve my contributions but I do not know what makes my answer not as good.

Answer (score 0):

There is an operator< for std::pair, which will compare first the first value and then the second. Thus, if you use the default comparison function, it will do the exact same thing: compare the first value. After that it will most likely stop, since the key value is likely to be sufficient to apply a sorting order.

The lambda does the same thing, of course, but the string_pairs are passed by value, and the additional copying is also taking some time. If you pass them by reference, presumably the speeds will be identical.

Comment: The reason why your answer was downvoted (not by me, I just did not vote on it): the "pass by reference" part at the end is correct, but everything before it is not really answering the question, and it is at least a bit misleading. It might also be that your relatively low "reputation" score it biasing people to disliking your wording.

Comment: He literally asks "The question finally ... Why is doing less costing more?". The first part explains why he is not actually "doing less", since the exact same comparison takes place. The second part explains the skewed timing due to pass-by-value.

Comment: There you go, you have it. This is the misleading (or even wrong) part. It is not the exact same comparison! The default comparison is to compare first, then if necessary second. In the question, it is a stable sort that uses only first (and **never** second) for the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the SWI-Prolog version, when using `keysort/2`, the sorting algorithm only compares the keys. But `sort/2` must compare the keys and, for any two pairs where the keys are the same, it must also compare the values. It is also possible/likely (I have not looked into the implementations of these predicates) that `keysort/2` goes for the keys in a direct way (given that the list members must be pairs using the `(-)/2)` infix operator) while `sort/2` must be able to deal with arbitrary terms which, for compound terms, implies traversing the whole term in the worst case using generic code. For pairs (which are, of course, a compound term), it means comparing the `(-)/2` functor, finding it to be the same, then descending into the arguments and comparing them. Thus, always twice the number of comparisons compared with `keysort/2`.

Comment: Which is why I am not surprised, but rather relieved by the timing comparison between `sort` and `keysort`.